# "You don't have permission to enable Compute Engine" with GCloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I've created a new project for a user and given them the role of `Compute Instance Admin`. However, when they first load the project they are getting the error "

> You don't have permission to enable Compute Engine.

As the owner, I need to visit the Compute page for the project to initialize it. At which point, users can then access Google Compute.

Is there a way to automate enabling Compute Engine for a project? Or, is there a role I can add the user to enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to automate enabling Compute Engine for a project?

With the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) installed,

```
$ gcloud service-management enable --project foo compute-component.googleapis.com
```

should do the trick. Otherwise, you can invoke [Google Service Management](https://cloud.google.com/service-management/overview) via some other method.

---

> Or, is there a role I can add the user to enable it?

From the [API docs](https://cloud.google.com/service-management/reference/rest/v1/services/enable):

> Authorization requires the following Google IAM permission on the specified resource `service_name`:
>
> ```
> servicemanagement.services.bind
> ```

Offhand, I don't know which roles have that permission.

Comment: Thank you, I used the Cloud SDK

Answer (score 1):

Enabling APIs requires a higher responsibility. The [`compute.instanceAdmin.v1`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#iam_roles) the role doesn't allow users to enable APIs.

If you are the owner and have enabled the `GCE API`, it might take a few minutes before the users can access `GCE`, as some resources need to be configured on the project like the default network, firewalls, and routes.

To enable APIs in a project, the minimum role required is project editor.

Comment: For a way to automate this, Zachary provided you already an answer.